# фон сделать за контейнером на полный экран

Tags: html, css, windows, веб-программирование, html-form

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header class="header">
            <div class="header__logotype">
                <a href="index.html" class="logo"><img src="assets/img/logo.svg" alt="logo"></a>
            </div>
        </header>   
    </div>
</body>
```

[![как в блоке welcome][1]][1]

фиолетовый фон на весь экран за контейнером
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjdAu.png

Comment: А вы делайте структуру типа `(.section>.wrapper)+(.section2>.wrapper)`, так гораздо проще в плане стилизации будет

Comment: Сам догадался уже, но всё же спасибо, что откликнулись